# How to execute commands through pipe in Python?

Tags: python, pipe, xargs

I use find and wc to get the total LOC using pipe.

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -print | xargs wc

  44     109     896 ./main.cpp
 ...
 288    1015    8319 ./src/util/util.cpp
 733    2180   21494 total
```

I need to automate getting LOC with python, I'll run the find .. | xargs command multiple times, get the result and process to get the total LOC.

How can I execute commands thorough pipe in Python?
I tried this, but it returns nothing.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['find', '.', '-name', "*.cc", "-print", "|", "xargs", "wc"], 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

### ADDED

With konishchev's hint, I could make it work.

```
p1 = Popen(['find', '.', '-name', "*.cc", "-print"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["xargs", "wc"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
print output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect two Popen objects like it described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

But I would like to recommend [psh module](http://konishchevdmitry.github.io/psh/intro.html#piping), because it much easier to use for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Piping is a shell function. Therefore your `Popen` call needs `shell=True` on it. Otherwise your `| wc` is going to be passed to `find`, which won't know what to do with it (and is probably sending an error to that effect into `err`... which you're not printing).

But why shell out at all? Just do all that stuff in Python (e.g. `os.walk` to replace `find`) It'll be easier to read and maintain. Something like:

```
import os, re
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".cc"):
            with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as infile:
                text = infile.read()
                chars = len(text)
                lines = sum(1 for x in re.finditer(r"\n", text))
                lines += not text.endswith("\n")  # count last line if no newline
                words = sum(1 for x in re.finditer(r"\w+", text))
                # do whatever with these...
```